# Data in D3.js brush (with fiddle example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Thanks for Your time. A simple question -

How could I add data ina  shape of a circle / bubble in a brusher itself ?
Here is my [brush](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/302/) and I'd like to add circles on say the 4th and the 10th days.

```
Data ?
```

Ive been trolling the internet up and down and couldnt find anything. please help.

Comment: You can do this in the same way in which you would add any other data-driven elements: http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/303/

Comment: I thought Ill be on Your ignore list. Thanks Lars, Ill have a look and definitely come back to You. Thanks

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff I have a a small diagram: One node called 'C' and some 'L's and 'R's. My aim here is to apply "two forces" so all the 'L's (left) would be pushed to the left and all the 'R's would be pushed to the right . here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/94/) . Is tehre anything You could suggest ? I've been researching force function but unsuccessfully as You can only apply force to all of the nodes not separately...

Comment: It sounds like you would need a custom force layout (or another custom layout) here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your suggestion a bit more please

Comment: Also maybe first approach would be to do it without a force ? A static network chart wits 'L' and 'R's , any ideas how to push them to opposite sides of the central node

Comment: That's what I mean -- compute the positions yourself. Assuming that you know which nodes should be left and right, it's easy to put them there.

Comment: So referring to my earlier example, how do you tell the node to be on the left or on the right ? Depending on the letter in this case, R and L, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand -- the data tells you where the node should be, doesn't it? All you have to do is set the position accordingly.

Comment: That's my point - do I need to specify x and y for every node ? Or can I somehow say all the Ls put them to the left of the central C node and the same for the R - to the right of the central C node.

Comment: If you know that the central node is at, say, position `100`, surely it's trivial to put the left nodes at a position smaller than `100`?

Comment: Makes sense. It's just every idea I have seems to me inefficient. I'll be putting up a big solution to all of my questions you answered and sharing here with the community. I'll put together a small fiddle maybe you could evaluate it and see if it's logically correct ? Is it possible to get your email ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see the problem...

Comment: Say I use your suggestion with the central node being at 100. I put the Ls with x being less than a 100 what about Y, does it nes essay need to be defined or can it be left blank so a random Y coordinate be assigned ?

Comment: That's entirely up to you -- does the y position matter or can it be random?

Comment: It can be random. Would you mind showing how to assign an X position but leave the Y to be random ?

Comment: That really depends on how you're assigning coordinates to elements. For circles, it would be something like `.attr("cx", 100).attr("cy", Math.random() * 1000)`.

Comment: I'll give that a go and see what comes out. Thanks